# Use windows cmd.exe to debug application in eclipse/CDT

Tags: windows, eclipse

I'm making a pdcurses application in C, using eclipse/CDT as the IDE.

Eclipse uses its own built-in console to run the application by default, but the process terminates right in the beginning, when i call the `initscr()` function.

I need it to run and debug the application using the cmd.exe console, and I'm almost sure that I did it in the past.

I searched everywhere, tried every possible configuration that they suggested and that I could remember of but couldn't get it right this time.

Can you shed some light upon me?

Thank you.